# Keras custom metric callback : how to acces val_data?

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I'm using a Unet model to do binary image segmentation ['forest', 'no forest'].
I use Keras with tf backend.
I use a `predict_generator()` with `validation_data` coming from my generator which yields batchs of (images, masks)

I want to use a custom callback with an `on_epoch_end` function that can store the confusion matrix for each epoch (on `validation_date`). But when I try to access my `validation_data`, I got an error `"NoneTypeObject"`

```
metric = Metrics()

model.fit_generator(myGene,
                    steps_per_epoch=100,
                    epochs=2,
                    verbose=1,
                    validation_data=val_gen,
                    validation_steps=100,
                    callbacks=[tbCallBack, model_checkpoint, metric]




class Metrics(tf.keras.callbacks.Callback):

    def on_train_begin(self, logs={}):

        self.confusion = []
        self.precision = []
        self.recall = []
        self.f1s = []
        self.kappa = []
        self.global_cm = []
        self.classes = ['forest', 'no forest']

    def on_batch_end(self, batch, logs={}):
        score = np.asarray(self.model.predict_on_batch(self.validation_data[0]))
        predict = np.round(np.asarray(self.model.predict_on_batch(self.validation_data[0])))
        predict = np.ravel(predict, order='C')
        targ = self.validation_data[1]
        targ = np.ravel(targ, order='C')

        self.confusion.append(confusion_matrix(targ, predict))
        self.precision.append(precision_score(targ, predict))
        self.recall.append(recall_score(targ, predict))
        self.f1s.append(f1_score(targ, predict))
        self.kappa.append(cohen_kappa_score(targ, predict))

    def on_train_end(self, logs={}):
        self.confusion = np.asarray(self.confusion)
        self.global_cm = np.sum(self.confusion, axis=0)
        print(self.global_cm)
```

The first line of `on_epoch_end()` fail to access `validation_data[0]` which correspond to a batch of validation images.

```
score = np.asarray(self.model.predict_on_batch(self.validation_data[0]))
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

Maybe should I write a custom keras metric instead of a callback, but how can I compute confusion matrix at the end of a batch then and how can I get the `validation_data` batch ?

Comment: You have too many incorrect lines in your code. Have you read the documentation on the functions you use? I suggest you to start from there. Solving this particular error (which is easy - just pass validation data and labels when you instantiate the class) would still require to rewrite most of your code.

Comment: Maybe I have inorrect lines after the error, but we dont care. With this code, with the debug mode, I see "None" for self.model.validation_data (at any time of the training)